# Android set listener for completed start service

Tags: android, android-service

i have problem with `start service` after running codes.

my service class:

```
 @Override
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    mApplication.setService(this);
 }
```

now:

```
 startService(intent); // service run sucess, but after millisecond delay
 mApplication.setIsServiceRunning(true);

 mApplication.getService().MyMethodAnyThing(); // <--- NullPointerExeption, because in my class mApplication.setService(this) do with delay and getService is null.
```

i need `completed start service`. example:

```
 startService(intent);
 mApplication.setIsServiceRunning(true);

 // i need like listener
 @Override
 onServiceIsRunComplete() {
      // here i'm sure that service is run
      mApplication.getService().MyMethodAnyThing();
 }
```

Comment: then use `bindService` and wait for a `ServiceConnection`

Comment: That's weird because service runs on the same thread as your activity

Comment: @TimCastelijns yeah, for me strange

Comment: This isn't wierd. Even though the `Service` is started on the same thread as your `Activity`, it isn't started immediately when you call `startService()`. All `startService()` does is put an event in the event queue that says "please start this service". Only after the Android framework gets control back will it process the events in the event queue. The Android framework doesn't get control back until whatever method you have running ends. Even then, there may be other events in the event queue that need to be processed before Android will start your `Service`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this,

```
protected ServiceConnection mServerConn = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onServiceConnected");
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onServiceDisconnected");
    }
}

public void start() {
    mContext.bindService(intent, mServerConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    mContext.startService(intent);
}
```

Also don't forget to unbindService() when stopping the service.